Metricbeat can't connect to Kibana - "Connection refused" on http://localhost:5601
I've been trying to configure Metricbeat with my Elastic Stack setup using Docker, but I keep getting an error where Metricbeat can't connect to Kibana. Here's the error log:
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-10-24T22:41:29.959Z","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1142},"message":"Exiting: error connecting to Kibana: fail to get the Kibana version: HTTP GET request to http://localhost:5601/api/status fails: fail to execute the HTTP GET request: Get \"http://localhost:5601/api/status\": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5601: connect: connection refused (status=0). Response: ","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}

It seems like Metricbeat is trying to connect to Kibana using localhost:5601, but the connection is refused. I'm using Docker Compose for the setup, and here is my docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.8"

networks:
  default:
    name: elastic
    external: false

services:
  metricbeat:
    depends_on:
      - kibana
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat:8.7.1
    user: root
    environment:
      - KIBANA_HOSTS=http://kibana:5601
    volumes:
      - ./metricbeatdata01:/usr/share/metricbeat/data
      - "./metricbeat.yml:/usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml:ro"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "/sys/fs/cgroup:/hostfs/sys/fs/cgroup:ro"
      - "/proc:/hostfs/proc:ro"
      - "/:/hostfs:ro"
    restart: on-failure
  
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.7.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    volumes:
      - es_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

  kibana:
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.7.1
    volumes:
      - kibanadata:/usr/share/kibana/data
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=kibana
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s -I http://localhost:5601 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

volumes:
  es_data:
    driver: local
  kibanadata:
    driver: local

And here's my metricbeat.yml:
metricbeat.modules:
- module: docker
  metricsets: ["container", "cpu", "diskio", "info", "memory", "network"]
  hosts: ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]
  period: 5s

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]

setup.kibana:
  hosts: kibana:5601

setup.dashboards.enabled: true


Ensured that setup.kibana.hosts is pointing to kibana:5601 in metricbeat.yml.
Verified that the Kibana service is up and running.
Increased the retries and intervals in Kibana's healthcheck.
Double-checked that Kibana is accessible from other services via http://kibana:5601 inside the    Docker network.
However, Metricbeat still seems to be trying to connect to localhost:5601 instead of kibana:5601. - I'm not sure why, and I'm stuck at this point.

Any ideas on what might be causing Metricbeat to fail to connect to Kibana?
